# Why .next folder is not installed after creating a next.js app?

Tags: next.js14

.next folder is not installed after next project installed..due to which my app is not working
.next folder is missing[after installation the folder is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D42uV.png)
after running my app this error shows[after npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxtY5.png)

I run command npm start but my app crashes with an error ie. .next folder is missing

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by issuing the command 'npm run build' in my VSCode terminal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).